# Not able to ping Windows Host machine from my Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am running docker container using Docker Desktop on Windows 2016 server. I am using Docker Desktop, instead of Docker EE on Windows 2016 server because I want to run Linux Container. Details of Docker is as follows: -

Version of Docker Desktop is

Version 2.0.0.3 (31259)
Channel: stable

Output of docker info is as follows: -

```
Containers: 3
Running: 1
Paused: 0
Stopped: 2
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.09.2
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Supports d_type: true
Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9754871865f7fe2f4e74d43e2fc7ccd237edcbce
runc version: 09c8266bf2fcf9519a651b04ae54c967b9ab86ec
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.125-linuxkit
Operating System: Docker for Windows
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.934GiB
Name: linuxkit-00155d2dab04
ID: OQK7:Z24A:V5KV:CYEW:6QQE:KXOB:UXWY:KVRF:QEHF:SATF:CTLU:WTPM
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
File Descriptors: 32
Goroutines: 53
System Time: 2020-02-26T06:36:51.0000459Z
EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

Output of docker version is as follows: -

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           18.09.2
API version:       1.39
Go version:        go1.10.8
Git commit:        6247962
Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

I am not able to ping my windows host machine from my Linux container.

But this is possible on my Windows 10 machine.

Any clue in this what I am missing???

Comment: can you share your ping error message? does ping time out, but can resolve the IP -> possible firewall issue. Ping can not resolve the hostname -> might point to DNS

Comment: ```[root@a47e23e069f6 /]# ping 192.168.45.171
PING 192.168.45.171 (192.168.45.171) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.65.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.65.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
``` Here 192.168.45.171 is my host machine. I don't know from where this 192.168.65.3 IP is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ifconfig` and check the IP of docker0 interface.

And ping using that IP.